# Insert banner div after 5 elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I have smarty template with this code:

with this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/kcdvrt8g/

And this is the output results:

```
<section id="listings" class="list clearfix">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
</section>
```

I want to add new div after each 5 article element  to be like this:

```
<section id="listings" class="list clearfix">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">

<div>test my content</div>

<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
</section>
```

Thank you,
Tariq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use  **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector for selecting by index
2. **[`after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/)** or **[`insertAfter()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)** for inserting element

```js
$('#listings .item:eq(4)').after($('<div/>', {
  html: 'test my content'
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="listings" class="list clearfix">
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
</section>
```

With your code :

```js
$('article.item:eq(4)').after($('<div/>', {
  html: 'test my content'
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="للايجار فيلا في المعموره" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-lm-mwrh-740.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad740/14414330711826604750.jpg&quot;);" alt="للايجار فيلا في المعموره" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad740/14414330711826604750.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad740/14414330711826604750_large.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"><span class="converted">EGP 43</span>
      <span style="display: none;">QAR 20</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_740" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_740" accesskey="740"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="للايجار فيلا في المعموره" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-lm-mwrh-740.html">للايجار فيلا في المعموره</a>

      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>Abu Hamour</span>
        <span>For Rent</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 05, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="للايجار فيلا في المعموره"  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-lm-mwrh-740.html"><div class="picture"><img alt="للايجار فيلا في المعموره" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif" style="background-image: url(http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad740/14414330711826604750.jpg);" /><span><span><span></span></span>1</span></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 20</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-lm-mwrh-740.html">للايجار فيلا في المعموره</a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="للايجار فيلا في مريخ" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-mrykh-739.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad739/1441432747314686609.jpg&quot;);" alt="للايجار فيلا في مريخ" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad739/1441432747314686609.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad739/1441432747314686609_large.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"> <span>QAR 0,000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_739" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_739" accesskey="739"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="للايجار فيلا في مريخ" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-mrykh-739.html">للايجار فيلا في مريخ</a>

      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>مريخ</span>
        <span>For Rent</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 05, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="للايجار فيلا في مريخ"  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-mrykh-739.html"><div class="picture"><img alt="للايجار فيلا في مريخ" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif" style="background-image: url(http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad739/1441432747314686609.jpg);" /><span><span><span></span></span>1</span></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 0,000</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-mrykh-739.html">للايجار فيلا في مريخ</a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="للإيجار فيلا أم صلال على " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-m-sll-l-738.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad738/1441432523123155960.jpg&quot;);" alt="للإيجار فيلا أم صلال على " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad738/1441432523123155960.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad738/1441432523123155960_large.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>2</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"> <span>QAR 000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_738" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_738" accesskey="738"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="للإيجار فيلا أم صلال على " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-m-sll-l-738.html">للإيجار فيلا أم صلال على </a>

      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>ام صلال</span>
        <span>For Rent</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 05, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="للإيجار فيلا أم صلال على "  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-m-sll-l-738.html"><div class="picture"><img alt="للإيجار فيلا أم صلال على " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif" style="background-image: url(http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad738/1441432523123155960.jpg);" /><span><span><span></span></span>2</span></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 000</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-m-sll-l-738.html">للإيجار فيلا أم صلال على </a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="للايجار على الإسكان " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-l-lskn-736.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad736/14414322561980318153.jpg&quot;);" alt="للايجار على الإسكان " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad736/14414322561980318153.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad736/14414322561980318153_large.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"><span class="converted">EGP 30,135</span>
      <span style="display: none;">QAR 14,000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_736" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_736" accesskey="736"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="للايجار على الإسكان " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-l-lskn-736.html">للايجار على الإسكان </a>

      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>ام صلال</span>
        <span>For Rent</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 05, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="للايجار على الإسكان "  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-l-lskn-736.html"><div class="picture"><img alt="للايجار على الإسكان " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif" style="background-image: url(http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad736/14414322561980318153.jpg);" /><span><span><span></span></span>1</span></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 14,000</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-l-lskn-736.html">للايجار على الإسكان </a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="للايجار فيلتين بالخريطيات" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyltyn-blkhrytyt-734.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad734/14414320351275707891.jpg&quot;);" alt="للايجار فيلتين بالخريطيات" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad734/14414320351275707891.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad734/14414320351275707891_large.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"> <span>QAR 0,000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_734" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_734" accesskey="734"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="للايجار فيلتين بالخريطيات" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyltyn-blkhrytyt-734.html">للايجار فيلتين بالخريطيات</a>

      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>الخريطيات</span>
        <span>For Rent</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 05, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="للايجار فيلتين بالخريطيات"  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyltyn-blkhrytyt-734.html"><div class="picture"><img alt="للايجار فيلتين بالخريطيات" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif" style="background-image: url(http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad734/14414320351275707891.jpg);" /><span><span><span></span></span>1</span></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 0,000</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyltyn-blkhrytyt-734.html">للايجار فيلتين بالخريطيات</a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="للايجار فيلا في الوعب " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-lw-b-729.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad729/1441431801280903304.jpg&quot;);" alt="للايجار فيلا في الوعب " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad729/1441431801280903304.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad729/1441431801280903304_large.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"> <span>QAR 0,000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_729" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_729" accesskey="729"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="للايجار فيلا في الوعب " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-lw-b-729.html">للايجار فيلا في الوعب </a>

      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>الوعب</span>
        <span>For Rent</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 05, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="للايجار فيلا في الوعب "  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-lw-b-729.html"><div class="picture"><img alt="للايجار فيلا في الوعب " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif" style="background-image: url(http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad729/1441431801280903304.jpg);" /><span><span><span></span></span>1</span></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 0,000</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llyjr-fyl-fy-lw-b-729.html">للايجار فيلا في الوعب </a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llby-fyl-fy-ldhyl-704.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad704/1441290572873536939.jpg&quot;);" alt="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad704/1441290572873536939.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad704/1441290572873536939_large.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"><span class="converted">EGP 21,525,100</span>
      <span style="display: none;">QAR 10,000,000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_704" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_704" accesskey="704"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llby-fyl-fy-ldhyl-704.html">للبيع فيلا في الدحيل </a>

      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>دحيل</span>
        <span>For Sale</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 03, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل "  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llby-fyl-fy-ldhyl-704.html"><div class="picture"><img alt="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif" style="background-image: url(http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad704/1441290572873536939.jpg);" /><span><span><span></span></span>1</span></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 10,000,000</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llby-fyl-fy-ldhyl-704.html">للبيع فيلا في الدحيل </a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llby-fyl-fy-ldhyl-699.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad699/1441290251347351975.jpg&quot;);" alt="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad699/1441290251347351975.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad699/1441290251347351975_large.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"><span class="converted">EGP 11,838,805</span>
      <span style="display: none;">QAR 5,500,000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_699" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_699" accesskey="699"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل " href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llby-fyl-fy-ldhyl-699.html">للبيع فيلا في الدحيل </a>

      </li>
      <li class="services"><span title="Bedrooms" class="badrooms">6</span><span title="Bathrooms" class="bathrooms">8</span>
      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>دحيل</span>
        <span>For Sale</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 03, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل "  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llby-fyl-fy-ldhyl-699.html"><div class="picture"><img alt="للبيع فيلا في الدحيل " src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif" style="background-image: url(http://aqarqatar.qa/files/09-2015/ad699/1441290251347351975.jpg);" /><span><span><span></span></span>1</span></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 5,500,000</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/llby-fyl-fy-ldhyl-699.html">للبيع فيلا في الدحيل </a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="أبا ظلوف الرويس" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/b-zlwf-lrwys-695.html">
      <div class="picture">
        <img style="background-image: url(&quot;http://aqarqatar.qa/files/49a928ec707db7177e5161cfbc41741e.jpg&quot;);" alt="أبا ظلوف الرويس" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif" data-1x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/49a928ec707db7177e5161cfbc41741e.jpg"
        data-2x="http://aqarqatar.qa/files/49a928ec707db7177e5161cfbc41741e.jpg" height="130" width="190">
        <span><span><span></span></span>0</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"><span class="converted">EGP 10,762</span>
      <span style="display: none;">QAR 5,000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_695" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_695" accesskey="695"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="أبا ظلوف الرويس" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/b-zlwf-lrwys-695.html">أبا ظلوف الرويس</a>

      </li>
      <li class="services"><span title="Bedrooms" class="badrooms">3</span><span title="Bathrooms" class="bathrooms">3</span><span title="Square Feet" class="square_feet">900 </span>
      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>For Rent</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 03, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
<!-- listing item -->
<article class="item">
  <div class="main-column">
    <a title="فلل في عين خالد (خدمية)" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/fll-fy-yn-khld-khdmy-694.html">
      <div class="picture no-picture">
        <img alt="فلل في عين خالد (خدمية)" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank_10x7.gif">
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="price-tag"><span class="converted">EGP 215,251</span>
      <span style="display: none;">QAR 100,000</span>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-column">
      <li id="fav_694" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to Favorites</span>
      </li>
      <li class="add_to_compare" title="Add to compare list" id="compare_icon_694" accesskey="694"><span class="icon"></span><span class="link">Add to compare list</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="info">
      <li class="title"> <a class="link-large" title="فلل في عين خالد (خدمية)" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/fll-fy-yn-khld-khdmy-694.html">فلل في عين خالد (خدمية)</a>

      </li>
      <li class="middle"></li>
      <li class="fields"> <span>عين خالد</span>
        <span>For Rent</span>
        <span> Villas &amp; Palaces</span>

      </li>
      <li class="system"> <span class="date">Sep 03, 2015</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> <span class="category-info hide"> <a href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses.html">Villas &amp; Palaces</a> </span>

  <script>
    listings_map.push(new Array('25.2916097,51.53043679999996', '<div class="map-balloon"><a title="فلل في عين خالد (خدمية)"  href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/fll-fy-yn-khld-khdmy-694.html"><div class="picture no-picture"><img alt="فلل في عين خالد (خدمية)" src="http://aqarqatar.qa/templates/XOOMSERVE/img/blank.gif"  /></div></a><div class="price-tag">QAR 100,000</div><div class="title"><a class="link-large" href="http://aqarqatar.qa/en/villa-houses/fll-fy-yn-khld-khdmy-694.html">فلل في عين خالد (خدمية)</a></div></div>', 'direct'));
  </script>
</article>
<!-- listing item end -->
```

Comment: I added the script in the Smarty template and I know your code is working in html perfectly but not in my smarty template..can you advise please?

Comment: Thank you again, I added the smarty code on this link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kcdvrt8g/)

Comment: can you provide the final rendering html output

Comment: Thank you again, I added the HTML output in this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vpmune1k/1/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88879/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-tariq-ahmed).

Comment: I'm really sorry for this delay...I have reasons....I tried the code but its only insert it once....can its repeat it self each 4 item and insert the same div? Thank you and forgave my delay.

Comment: Thank you again and again....actually, I found that I need to add other div already placed in the same page...not HTML code....is this possible?

Comment: `$('#listings .item:eq(4)').after($('#divid'));` or if you want to copy then `$('#listings .item:eq(4)').after($('#divid').clone());`

Comment: Great brother :) work like charm....no words explain how much I would like to say thank you.

Comment: @TariqAhmed : glad to help you bro :) :)