# Load div with its content after each 5 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smarty3

I have smarty template with the output code on this link:

[My other Question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411382/insert-banner-div-after-5-elements-using-javascript)

My issue that the code which provided there not: Repeating the inserted HTML each 5 elements...

Can someone help by providing solution make me able to insert other dive contents after each 5 elements to have final out put look like this:

```
    <section id="listings" class="list clearfix">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">

**OTHER DIV BY CLASS OR ID**

<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">


**OTHER DIV BY CLASS OR ID**

<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">


**OTHER DIV BY CLASS OR ID**

<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
<article class="item">
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [**nth-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) selector and [**after()**](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$('.item:nth-child(5n)').after('<article>inserted after 5th</article>');
```

```js
$('.item:nth-child(5n)').after('<article>inserted after 5th</article>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="listings" class="list clearfix">
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>



  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>




  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>



  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
  <article class="item">test</article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much....can I add div with its contents has a class or id? for example I already have div with a banner, I need to repeat it with your code

Comment: @TariqAhmed, why not store the html in a variable like `var div = '<div id="myId"></div>` and then use it in after like `.after(div)`

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to

> can I add div with its contents has a class or id? for example I
>   already have div with a banner, I need to repeat it with your code

You can render it somwhere on the page like script element with unknown type (it will be ignored by browser), like this:

```
<script type="template/banner" id="div-banner">
    <div class="banner">
      <img src=".../NNNxNNN/banner.png" />
    </div>
</script>
```

And then insert it like suggested:

```
$('.item:nth-child(5n)').after($("#div-banner").html());
```

It will keep yours JavaScript cleaner and wouldn't pollute global scope with junk variables.